# Name of this type of crimps?

Tags: crimp

Does anyone know an official name for this type of crimps?

[image]

I am seeing them all the time but never know its proper name. The [seller](https://www.pololu.com/product/1930) calls them "Female Crimp Pins for 0.1" Housings". They are made for this type of housing:

[image]

Comment: Those only have a name in the sense of the sense of the part numbers given to them by each manufacturer who makes them in the same name way 0.100" square headers also don't have a name. Furthermore, even though the crimp terminals all plug into a 0.100" square header pin, they may only work with the crimp housing for which they were intended.

Comment: By the way, if you've never heard or Mouser or Digikey, you can always search these up based on their specifications on there. Much better than wading through hobbyists websites where nothing has a true specification or part number.

Comment: @DKNguyen I am trying to buy these handy and cheap wire-to-wire connectors from mouser or RS components, but scanning through their huge category to find this is difficult...

Comment: Dupont header crimp.

Comment: Going by the other answers here, it looks to me like what you're asking about is what type of *connector* this is, not the type of *crimp* (which refers to the specific method by which the crimp connection is made, and thus what crimp dies you would use to crimp it). Please be more clear what you're asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These connectors were called "Dupont connectors" long time ago, and you can still find them under this name [all over the web](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000227827798.html).

However the online suppliers like Mouser and Digikey do not use this name anymore, because over the years it was used by many similar but not compatible products.

The easiest way to find them is under "Rectangular connectors" category, with 0.100" (2.54mm) pitch filter. Here is [one at digikey](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/harwin-inc/M20-1060400/3728193), for example.

If you are looking for a crimp, most of the suppliers [have links](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/harwin-inc/M20-1160042/3728123) to "Associated Products" right on the housing page. I am not aware of any generic name for this type of crimps. For me they always were "crimps that go with that thing" kind of things.

Comment: I'd never heard them referred to as 'DuPont' connectors apart from in recent times. In the early days there were 'Berg' pins - Berg being a division of Dupont. The recent reference to Dupont I put down to a Chinese mis-translation, just like 'welding', 'pcb oil' and 'coruscate'.

Comment: @Kartman Nor I anywhere off this website. I have also never been able to actually find a company named Dupont that actually makes these. Did they go under? Even if it did, calling them Dupont is just as bad as calling them Molex, JST, or Tyco connectors. It won't help you when you're looking at authorized distributors.

Comment: @DKNguyen not using the name at authorized distributors was the whole point of my answer. But the search for "dupont connectors" returns almost 3 millions hits on google. 125 hits on this site alone. I am surprised you've never heard of it

Answer (score 4):

Those only have a name in the sense of the sense of the part numbers given to them by each manufacturer who makes them in the same name way 0.100" square headers also don't have a name. Furthermore, even though the crimp terminals all plug into a 0.100" pitch, 0.025" square header pins, they may only work with the crimp housing for which they were intended.

> @DKNguyen I am trying to buy these handy and cheap wire-to-wire connectors from mouser or RS components, but scanning through their huge category to find this is difficult... – Anthony 19 mins ago

I did the same thing you are trying to do now years ago ago and remember it being kind of a PITA and ended up saving the webpage.

It's hopeless to try and find the crimp contact in a vacuum. They aren't really identifiable on paper or through photos. But you can identify the the header (0.100" pitch with 0.025" square posts) which leads you to the crimp housing that goes with them (which you could also probably identify in which case you can skip the identification of the header). So start with what you know and follow the trail. The process I went through was:

1. Find the actual series name, series number, and part number for the crimp housing on Digikey/Mouser
2. Go onto the Molex website armed with that information to their web page about the crimp housing itself
3. Follow that webpage (or backtrack to higher levels depending on the the website is organized) to find the crimp contacts it was compatible with.

That gave me all possible combinations of everything they had available. I never bothered for other manufacturers. If you want another manufacturer then it's probably a similar process. The generic crimp housing and header specifications is 0.100"/2.54 mm pitch crimp housing with 0.025" square posts.

In my saved webpage from the Molex website, the high-force female crimp numbers are 16-02-1125/1109/1115/1117/1114/1116. The regular force crimp numbers are: 16-02-0102/0096/0103/0104/0097/0098. The difference between the six part numbers in each group are all possible combinations AWG (22-24AWG vs 24-30AWG) and plating (150u Sn, 15u Au, or 30u Au).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is very informative and offers great guide for electronic newbies like me. Sorry but I cannot accept it an "answer", as @Maple has provided a name for the connector in question which results in lots of valid searches. It will benefit those who have to use these type of connectors to work with some off-the-shelf electronics. They are very commonly found on cheap servos widely used in UAV research labs.

Answer (score 0):

This type of crimp is commonly referred to as an F type crimp, or an open-barrel crimp.

Comment: One would be hard-pressed finding these under "F type crimp", that being associated with coax connector for ages. The name is fitting though, that's exactly how they look from the side.

Comment: Yes, open barrel is a better term for finding it.